# conditional derivative usage of macro in cpp

Tags: c++, c, macros, debug-print

I have a question. In one of my projects i am using the FLAG PRINT to enable/disable the debug printfs. currently I am using something like this.

```
#ifdef PRINT
    printf("DEBUG");
#endif
```

It is a pain to put this #ifdef before every printf. So I was thinking to 've a #define for the #ifdef, something like

```
#define DEBUG_PRINT 
#define PRINT (#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT)
#define ENDPRINT #endif
```

so that I can use like

```
PRINT
   printf("DEBUG");
ENDPRINT
```

but it is giving a compiler error. Can you tell me someway to simplify.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

A standard way is

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
#  define is_debug() (1)
#else
#  define is_debug() (0)
#endif

#define pr_dbg(fmt, ...) do { \
        if (is_debug()) \
            printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__); \
    } while (0)
```

When using gcc, you can/should write

```
            printf(fmt, ## __VA_ARGS__);
```

to deal with empty args.

In your code you can write then

```
pr_dbg("foo=%u\n", foo);
```

Optimizer will throw away the expression when `DEBUG_PRINT` is not defined but your debug statements will be still checked for syntax errors. This avoids silent breakage when e.g. undefined variables are used within an `#ifdef` clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about a header with

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define ON_DEBUG(X,...) do { X, __VA_ARGS__; } while( false )
#else
#define ON_DEBUG(X,...) do {} while( false )
#endif
```

and in your code, you simply use

```
ON_DEBUG( printf("Hallo, %s", "Welt") );
```

(the `do`-`while` forces you to add the final semicolon and protects the statement's in cases if (nested) `if`-statements, see Aaron McDaid's comment)

Comment: That could behave in a very weird way sometimes.  Consider `if (x) ON_DEBUG( printf("hello"); printf("world"); ) else something();`. This `if` would pick up only the first printf. Instead you should do `#define ON_DEBUG(X,...) do { X,__VA_ARGS__ }while(0)`

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do it a different way entirely.  First define the flag that turns printing on or off:

```
// uncomment to turn off debug printing
#define DEBUG_PRINT 1
```

Then conditionally define your printer macro depending of the definition state of `DEBUG_PRINT`:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_PRINT
#define PRINT (X) (printf(x))
#else
#define PRINT (x)
#endif
```

Which can be used simply as:

```
PRINT("foo");
```

---

But in reality, I wouldn't do any of this stuff at all.  Instead, I'd have the turn-on/turn-off flag as above, and then build a *class* that does the printing:

```
// comment out to not do debug printing
//#define DEBUG_PRINTING 1

#ifdef DEBUG_PRINTING
class Printer
{
public:
    Printer() {}
    ~Printer()
    {
        std::cout << mOutput.str() << "\n";
    }

    template <typename TYPE> Printer& operator<< (const TYPE& val)
    {
        mOutput << val;
        return * this;
    }
    template <size_t N> Printer& operator<<  (const char(&ary)[N])
    {
        mOutput << ary;
        return * this;
    }
private:
    std::stringstream mOutput;
};
#else
class Printer
{
public:
    Printer() {};
    template <typename TYPE> Printer& operator<< (const TYPE& val)
    {
        return * this;
    }
    template <size_t N> Printer& operator<< (const char(&ary)[N])
    {
        return * this;
    }
};
#endif

int main()
{
    Printer() << "My output here. " << 42;
}
```

In optimized builds where the flag is not defined, most (if not all) of the code will be optimized away.